Given the matrix B, prove that $Id,B,B^2,B^3$ and $B^4$ are linearly dependent
Given the matrix $B=(A+J)$, where $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and $J=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$
. Prove that $Id,B,B^2,B^3, B^4$ are linearly depenendent (as a real vector space). I am looking for a solution that does not require a lot of effort nor brute force, like a pattern or something that simplify the problem. My try started with binomial expansion and the following facts: $J^2=Id$ and $A=S+Id$ where $S$ is an upper triangular matrix with zeroes in the diagonal so $S^4=0$. I think I am missing an additional fact.

Have tried to determine the eigenvalues ? If they are different the conclusion holds.

@RyszardSzwarc Could you explain a little bit more this approach with eigenvalues?

Doesn't it just follow from Cayley-Hamilton theorem? The characteristic polynomial of $B$ has degree $4$.

Did not think about it, nice point!

Degree 4 doesn't help in general. Consider $B=0.$  The characteristic polynomial is $x^4.$

If the eigenvalues of $B$ are different say $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_4$ then $B$ is similar to the diagonal matrix $D$ with these eigenvalues on the main diagonal. The linear independence of $I, B, B^2, B^3$ is equivalent to the linear independence of $I, D, D^2, D^3.$ The latter is easy to prove as the polynomial of fourth degree has at most four different eigenvalues If $B$ does admit multiple eigenvalues then we need to use some other ways.

I apologize for misundersting the question. I thought you wanted to show that $I,B,B^2,B^3$ are linearly independent.

Exactly what @Mark said: $\det(xI-B)$ is a (non zero) four degree polynomial, and so Cayley Hamilton theorem gives a linear relation between $I$, $B$, $B^2$, $B^3$ and $B^4$.

For $A=0$ the characteristic polynomial is equal $x^4.$ But $I,A,A^2,A^3$ are not linearly independent.

@RyszardSzwarc: But $I$, $A$, $A^2$, $A^3$ and $A^4$ are.

According to me they are not linearly independent as ${I,A,A^2,A^3}={I,0,0,0}.$ Adding $A^4=0$ doesn't change anything.

Sorry, I was not careful enough reading the OP. I thought the asker was after linear independence of $I,B,B^2,B^3.$ Clearly adding $B^4$ gives the linear dependence.

According to Wolphram Alpha the characteristic polynomial of $C:=B-I$ is equal $x^4-4x^2-6.$ The equation has four differents   roots. Thus $B$ has $4$ different roots $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_4.$ Assume
$$\alpha_0I+\alpha_2B+\alpha_2B^2+\alpha_3B^3=0$$ then the polynomial $$p(x)=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2x^2+\alpha_3x^3$$ has four different roots $\lambda_j,$ $1\le j\le 4. $ Thus $p(x)\equiv 0,$ hence $\alpha_j=0,$ $0\le j\le 3.$ This concludes the proof of linear independence of $I,B,B^2,B^3.$
Remark I have mixed up the question. For any $n\times n$ matrix $B$ the matrices $I,B,\ldots B^n$ are linearly dependent. But it is possible that $I,B,\ldots, B^{n-1}$ are   linearly independent.

This was not asked on the question but it is a really nice point, thanks!
